# Deploying mysql galera cluster on aws Ec2 vs VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc, galera

I am tying to deploy galera cluster on aws. Is it a good idea to use VPC or making a cluster with 2-3 open ec2 instances. What are pros and cons.

Also, Is there any extra billing for VPC? Any help will be great!!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the variation of the installation of the GALERA on AWS VPC with EC2 instances.

One suggestion which I would add is the consideration of the RDS - Database as a service from AWS; I don't whether that would solve your need to use GALERA.

Regarding the pricing for the VPC, it is free; you only pay for the underlying EC2 instances running, Elastic IP - Data Transfer, Out Bandwidth etc. If you are going to connect your local data center to VPC using VPC/VPN gateway - that would be charged

Answer (score 0):

- No there is no extra cost for a VPC [but only for the resources used in it]
- With Galera you can have a multi-master architecture [I have not implemented it] but with RDS you cannot. I have setup a Disaster Recovery plan with RDS where a multi-master architecture would be eliminating the downtime , but instead set it up with the use of Read Replica which would be promoted in a master. That's the way AWS RDS works.